# Why my wordpress loop modifies my html code?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

for the first time I'm facing a problem that I can't explain. I'm creating a simple wordpress loop for a gallery but, I don't know why, the loop change my html code inside the loop.

At first, this is what I wrote :

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=9'); 
    if ( have_posts() ) : 
        while ( have_posts() ) : 
            the_post(); 
?>

<?php
            $post_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_to_use->ID);
            if ($post_image_id) {
                $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_image_id, 'large', false);
                if ($thumbnail) 
                    (string)$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
            } else {
                $thumbnail = './assets/no-picture.jpg';
            }
?>
            
    <article class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="#Modal1" data-toggle="modal" class="gallery-box">
            <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
            <div class="gallery-box-caption">
                <div class="gallery-box-content">
                    <div>
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <h6 class='wide-space'><?php the_category(); ?></h6>
                        <i class="icon-lg ion-ios-play-outline"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But when it's launched online, the code inside the loop become this :

```
<article class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <a href="#Modal1" data-toggle="modal" class="gallery-box">
        <img src="https://labelleequipeproductions.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/lessines-terre-de-developpement.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
    </a>
    <div class="gallery-box-caption">
        <a href="#Modal1" data-toggle="modal" class="gallery-box"></a>
        <div class="gallery-box-content">
            <a href="#Modal1" data-toggle="modal" class="gallery-box">
            </a>
            <div>
                <a href="#Modal1" data-toggle="modal" class="gallery-box">
                    <h2>Lessines, Terre de développement</h2>
                </a>
                <h6 class="wide-space">
                    <a href="#Modal1" data-toggle="modal" class="gallery-box"></a>
                    <ul class="post-categories">
                        <a href="#Modal1" data-toggle="modal" class="gallery-box"></a>
                        <li><a href="#Modal1" data-toggle="modal" class="gallery-box"></a>
                            <a href="https://labelleequipeproductions.com/category/corporate/" rel="category tag">Corporate</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </h6>
                    <i class="icon-lg ion-ios-play-outline"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Are there someone who could help me on this ? I never seen this before and I often use this kind of loop.

Comment: _Small Note_ You really dont need an `if ( have_posts() ) :` followed by a `while ( have_posts() ) :` as if there are no posts the while will do nothing anyway

Comment: Make sure you dont have some old code cached somewhere, as I dont see how that code could produce that output